Is There A Better Deterministic Discrete Logarithm Decision Algorithm?
I recently wrote a fairly simple discrete log calculator (here https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Discrete-Log) which works pretty efficiently for small numbers, in my case moduli below $2^{32}$. It uses the following well known algorithm.
To solve $a^e = b$ mod $n$ for $e$ where $0<a<n$ and $n>1$ are relatively prime and $0<b<n$ and $n$ are relatively prime,
Let $m$ = $\lceil\sqrt n\rceil$,
For $i = 0$ to $m-1$
   if $a^i = b$ mod $n$, return $i$
   insert [$a^i$ mod $n$, $i$] into a hash map $H$
Let $x = a^{-m}$ mod $n$
For $j = 0$ to $m-1$
   if [$bx^j$ mod $n$, $i$] in $H$, return $jm+i$
Report no solutions.
The memory requirement for the hash map is O($mE$) where $E$ is the size of a single element. The issue I have is that I want to be able to still get good worst case performance for larger $n$, and a memory requirement that a typical PC or laptop can handle, say a few gigabytes. The worst case performance happens when $n$ is large and there is no solution.
I know there are fast probabilistic algorithms for calculating discrete logarithms, but I want to be sure that no solution exists if my program does not find a solution. I don't know how to make use of probabilistic algorithms to achieve this without accepting some small chance that it might not find a solution when one exists. This probability might be of a magnitude that is not a concern in most practical applications, but I'm interested in how to achieve determinism anyway for $n < 2^{64}$ and eventually beyond.
Using the same method for $n < 2^{64}$ as my program for $n < 2^{32}$ would require up to $2^{32}$ elements inserted into a hash map, and up to to $2^{32}$ random reads from the hash map. Even if I had enough RAM, that could take minutes. Space and time optimisations I have considered are as follows.
To reduce the RAM requirement, reduce the number of elements that need to be inserted into the hash map by a factor of $k$, at the expense of having to perform up to $k$ times more look-ups.
Factorising $n$, and calculating the multiplicative order $o$ of $a$ mod $p$ for each prime factor $p$ of $n$ and solving $a^e = b$ mod $p$ as above with $m = \lceil\sqrt o\rceil$. This would be a good optimisation for the general case, but $n$ can be prime, and the largest prime factor of $o$ can be of a similar order of magnitude to $p$ so this optimisation doesn't much help improve the worst case performance.
I know for a solution to exist the order of $b$ must divide the order of $a$ which might catch a lot of cases, but not all.
I know that if the multiplicative order of $a$ mod $n$ is $n-1$, there is a solution.
Is there a faster deterministic test that tests if $a^e = b$ mod $n$ has no solution $e$?
[Added group theory tag as question is to determine if $b$ is in $<a>$ or a coset.]
